# A partial converse to the stability of separatedness under base change

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $S$ be a base scheme, and let $X/S$ be an $S$-scheme. Let $T/S$ be another scheme. Denote the base change of $X$ to $T$ by $X_T := X \times_S T$.

Now separatedness (resp. properness) are stable under base change, so if $X/S$ is separated then so is $X_T/T$.

I am searching for a (partial) converse to this. In its most general form

> Suppose $X$ is a scheme over a base scheme $S$, and suppose that $T/S$ is a scheme. If $X_T$ is separated (resp. proper) over $T$, is $X$ separated (resp. proper) over $S$?

In this generality the claim is false: (and this may be an overkill example) consider $G$ the affine line with doubled origin over $S = \operatorname{Spec} k[t]$ (with $S$-group scheme structure), and its base change $G_T$ to $T = \operatorname{Spec} k(t)$. The first is not separated, but the second is a group scheme over a field, hence separated.

But can we impose sufficiently strong conditions (on $X$, $S$, and $T$) under which this holds?

An example of when this would be useful is if $k$ is a field of characteristic zero, $S = \operatorname{Spec} k$, $T = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}$, and $X$ is something reasonable (since in this case we can check hausdorfness and compactness in the analytification by GAGA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general name for this problem is "descent". The answer to your question is affirmative: if $T\to S$ is fpqc (faithfully flat and quasi-compact) then separatedness descends along $T\to S$, so $X_T/T$ separated implies $X/S$ separated. For a source, see EGA IV2, 2.7.1(i), or [these notes](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/216APage/handouts/fpqc.pdf) of Matt Emerton. (For quick lookups, the best place to check whether some property is stable under descent is the table at the end of Poonen's "Rational Points on Varieties", a copy of which is available at the author's website.)

Here's a sketch of the proof: consider the (cartesian) diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X_T @>{\Delta}>> X_T\times_T X_T\\
@VVV @VVV \\
X @>{\Delta}>> X\times_S X
\end{CD}$$

where the horizontal maps are the diagonal morphisms. The top row is actually the base change of the bottom row along the map $T\to S$, so it's fpqc as that's preserved by arbitrary base change. The top row is also a closed immersion by assumption, so it suffices to show that closed immersions descend along fpqc maps. Checking this claim is local and amounts to the statement that if $A\to B$ is a surjective map of rings and $A\to A'$ is a faithfully flat map of rings, then $A\otimes_A A'\to B\otimes_A A'$ is also surjective. So $X\to X\times_S X$ is a closed immersion, and thus $X/S$ is separated.

Comment: Thank you, the comment about descent is a gold mine - I had only seen this in the Galois and etale contexts for finding a model of a variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$, and somehow my brain has never triggered that "adjective"-descent is clearly more general.

Comment: Great, glad to help - descent is indeed pretty awesome.